# Android garbage collector very slow to free up memory

Tags: android, garbage-collection, android-imageview

I have defined a `ViewGroup` that can come in and out of screen. When out of screen, all of it's subviews are destroyed to save memory and these get recreated when the View comes into screen.

Most of these subviews are `ImageView`s that use a standard `android:src=@drawable` to draw the bitmap.

To destroy subviews, I call `viewGroup.removeAllViews()`

Problem is the garbage collector takes some time to actually free up the memory and the app's heap size increases dramatically if I open/close `ViewGroup` repeatedly.

Is there a way around this?

Comment: "To destroy subviews, I call viewGroup.removeAllViews()" why did you start doing this? why are you trying to save memory, are you getting out of memory exceptions?

Comment: @weston I'm in a critical memory situation where I want to keep my app's ram at a minimum

Comment: Doesn't answer my question. Are you getting outofmemory exceptions?

Comment: @weston no, that's not the reason I'm doing this

Comment: What's this critical memory situation you're talking about? What problem are you having/trying to solve?

Comment: @weston I need to keep the app's memory at a minimum for low end devices

Comment: On lower end devices, you'll see a smaller heap and garbage collection will be more active. Also images will be loaded at smaller dpis on those devices and take less memory. Bottom line I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: @weston I know, this problem only happens on higher end devices where the heap increases. But since the problem eventually disappears when the gc fires, I'll ignore it for now. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

> When out of screen, all of it's subviews are destroyed to save memory and these get recreated when the View comes into screen.

Only do this if it is likely that the `ViewGroup` will never be used again in this activity. As it stands, you are causing your own problem, by releasing and re-allocating the same stuff repeatedly.

Comment: It is unlikely that it's used again. The problem I'm trying to solve is an edge case

Comment: @liarspocker: Then I wouldn't worry about the heap size increase. The garbage collector will eventually catch up, and on ART, your heap will shrink back down sometime after your app moves to the background.

Comment: Exactly, it gets sorted eventually

Comment: @liarspocker: "I'm in a critical memory situation where I want to keep my app's ram at a minimum" -- then you are going to need to weigh the criticality of the normal case compared to this edge case. We don't know enough to really guide you as to which is the lesser of the two evils. Or, find a way to do the whole thing with a lot less heap space to begin with.